# Wordpress, calling a class method from a template part

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to call a method defined in a custom plugin from a custom template part.

In my plugin, I've defined a class, and initiate it via `$users_activity = new OBJ_user_activity();`.

The following works while in main template (`author.php`, `page.php`) ...

```
$users_activity->get_currently_online_users_count();
```

... But doesn't work with a custom template part. Instead I'm getting a the following error:

> Call to undefined variable $users_activity.

Would anyone know how to correctly call a method from a custom template part ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get_template_part()` allows a 3rd parameter to pass in variables.

- Source @ https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/176807/193195

---

Based on your question:

```
get_template_part( 'templates/app', 'aside', array( 'users_activity' => $users_activity ) );
```

... and from the template part:

```
echo $args['users_activity']->get_currently_online_users_count();
```